# nodejs read image headers

Tags: http, node.js, mime-types, fs

I'm writing a script to download files from urls in a list. The problem I'm having is that the urls don't just point to static files, like `file.jpg`, they tend to point to servlets that return a file.

What I want to do is download the file for each url and save it with a generic name, then read its headers and rename it with the appropriate extension. (Unless there's a better way)

How could I do that?

I've tried using mime-magic, but it tells me that the extension-less files are directories.

Comment: actually it should work using mime-magic, are you sure the path is correct and the path is not pointing to a directory? otherwise you could use the command line tool `file --mime /path/to/file`

Comment: Thanks, I'm dumb. The wget command I used created a directory and placed a file inside of that directory :/

Comment: You should put your response as an answer so I can close the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work using `mime-magic`. Are you sure the path is correct and the path is not pointing to a directory?

Otherwise you could use the command line tool `file --mime /path/to/file`

Here is how to detect an extension of a file using [`mime-magic`](https://github.com/SaltwaterC/mime-magic):

```
mime('/path/to/foo.pdf', function (err, type) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        // ERROR: cannot open `/path/to/foo.pdf' (No such file or directory)
    } else {
        console.log('Detected mime type: %s', type);
        // application/pdf
    }
});
```

**Note**: Added sled's comment as an answer under community-wiki.